# Asp.Net Drop Down Not Selecting Blank Value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a Dropdown in which i am appending value like this

```
        ddMeetPoint.prepend($("<option></option>").val(' ').text(' ').attr("IsDefault", "N"));

        $.each(jsdata, function (key, value) {
            ddMeetPoint.append($("<option></option>").val(key).text(key).attr("IsDefault", value));
        });
```

First Option is Blank/Empty and if select first blank option like this:

```
      selectedText = MyDropDown.SelectedItem.Text;
```

I always getting 2 Item Of dropdown which has some value.

I want to get blank/empty value whenever I select that, how to do this

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the ASP.NET viewstate , when control was loaded it did not have the first item which you added from the client side but the viewstate does not have the added option. SO for the server control the first value is still the same when it render.

To make it work add the empty option list on the server side before final rendering. This is how ASP.NET Works. If it is MVC it would have worked with ease.

Comment: But I am getting valued of drop down from service and now it always selecting blank value